# How to handle deep link in navigation component

Tags: android, deeplink

I have error while using deep link so it is:

when click web-link app opens, after it should go to the history fragment
but in my case i have fingerprint page, which after goes to home fragment,
but i want it should go history page

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

when you click the deeplink and open the application, you have uri intent.

```
public void checkDeepLink(){
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String action = intent.getAction();
   Uri data = intent.getData();
   if (data != null && //something check about data) {
      Constants.FROM_DEEPLINK = true //define a static constant
   }
}
```

When you open home fragment, you will check `FROM_DEEPLINK` and open history page.

Comment: you know how to get data using navigation component 
<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />

?